# Select 1 record where two records have the the same values in different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains two columns.

[image: Table snap]

in the first two rows the values for the columns are reversed, how would I select one record for every instance where one STATION_1_I equals another records STATION_2_I and its STATION_2_I equals STATION_1_I.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[INTERSECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries004.htm) will remove duplicates for you

```
select "station_1_I", "station_2_I" from mytable
intersect
select "station_2_I", "station_1_I" from mytable 
             where "station_2_I" < "station_1_I"
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8bd6/1)

Comment: this will not work, assuming you have this set of record `1,2` and `2,1`, how will this intersect work on `2,1` and `1,2`? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/171dc/1

Comment: @jfin3204: my bad sorry, missed a WHERE clause

Answer (score 2):

```
select a,b from
(
select 
(case when a<b then a else b end) as a,
(case when a>b then a else b end) as b
from (
select station_1_I as a, station_2_I as b from MyTable
union all
select station_2_I, station_1_I from MyTable
) having count(*)=2 group by a,b
) group by a,b
```

Comment: Ah, you don't need both duplicates? OK, now I understand. Will edit answer according to that.

Comment: And, by the way, I tried to make it work on those RDBMSes, whish does not support `intersect`